# How to run jenkins comand from console?

Tags: jenkins

I want to run jenkins build command:

```
 py.test tests
```

from the ubuntu console. How to do it?

Comment: What is happend if you enter the command on console?

Comment: it can run tests. But I want nowt just run tests, I want to start current build in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer:

```
curl --user <your_jenkins_username>:<your_jenkins_API_key> http://<jenkins_server_url>/job/<your_jenkins_job_name>/build
```